# Element flashing briefly before sliding, interfering with the smoothness of the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I've been making my own version of a slider, with many different iterations, and feel that I'm almost there with how I want it to function.

Here is the demo of the slider: http://codepen.io/zephyr/pen/ZYgwNX

CODE:

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="https://cdn.photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Nikon-D810-Image-Sample-7.jpg" alt="This is a picture of stuff in the sea" title="Sea">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://cdn.photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Nikon-D810-Image-Sample-6.jpg" alt="This is a picture of an island with a beach" title="Beach">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://hdwallpaperia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Nature-Image-Wallpapers-HD-1024x576.jpg" alt="This is a picture of a night city" title="City">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://wallpoper.com/images/00/43/54/14/sakura-cherry-blossom_00435414.jpg" alt="These are some sakura blossoms" title="Sakura Blossoms">
    </li>
    <div class="arrows left"></div>
    <div class="arrows right"></div>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="picture-description">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="description"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {margin:0;}

*,*:before,*:after {
  transition:all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.3s;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.slider,
.slider-info {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.picture-description {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color:#eee;
}

.picture-description .wrap {
  position:relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:300;
}

.title {
  font-size:24px;
  letter-spacing:1px;
}
.description {
  font-size:16px;
  letter-spacing:1px;
}

.slider ul {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.slider ul li {
  position:absolute;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  transition:none;
  -webkit-transition:none;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.slider ul li img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  bottom: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
  right: -9999px;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: initial;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media (min-width:1200px){
  .slider,
  .slider ul li,
  .picture-description {
    min-height: 300px;
  }
}
@media (min-width:768px){
  .slider,
  .slider ul li,
  .picture-description {
    height: calc(50vh - 52.5px);
    min-height: 370px;
  }
}


@media (max-height:530px) and (min-width:768px){
  .slider,
  .slider ul li,
  .picture-description {
    height: calc(100vh - 105px);
    min-height: 400px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:768px){
  .slider,
  .picture-description {
    width:100%;
  }
  .slider,
  .slider ul li,
  .picture-description {
    height:calc(50vh - 52.5px);
    min-height:calc(50vh - 52.5px);
    max-height:calc(50vh - 52.5px);
  }
}



/**
* iPad with portrait orientation.
*/
@media all and (device-width: 768px)
and (device-height: 1024px)
and (orientation:portrait){
  .slider,
  .slider ul li,
  .picture-description {
    height: 1024px;
  }
}

/**
* iPad with landscape orientation.
*/
@media all and (device-width: 768px)
and (device-height: 1024px)
and (orientation:landscape){
  .slider,
  .slider ul li,
  .picture-description {
    height: 768px;
  }
}

/**
* iPhone 5
* You can also target devices with aspect ratio.
*/
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) {
  .slider,
  .slider ul li,
  .picture-description {
    height: 500px;
  }
}


.arrows {
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:80px;
  top: 0;
  cursor:pointer;
  z-index:3;
}

.arrows.left {
  left:0;
}
.arrows.right {
  right:0;
}

.arrows.left:hover,
.arrows.left:active,
.arrows.left:focus {
  box-shadow: 40px 0 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset;
}
.arrows.right:hover,
.arrows.right:active,
.arrows.right:focus {
  box-shadow: -40px 0 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset;
}

.arrows:after {
  content:'';
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
  border-right: 4px solid #000;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
}

.arrows.left:after {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  left: 20px;
}
.arrows.left:hover:after {
  border-width: 3px;
  left: 15px;
}
.arrows.left:active:after,
.arrows.left:focus:after {
  border-width: 4px;
  left: 17px;
}

.arrows.right:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 20px;
}
.arrows.right:hover:after {
  border-width: 3px;
  right: 15px;
}
.arrows.right:active:after,
.arrows.right:focus:after {
  border-width: 4px;
  right: 17px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$.fn.slideIt = function(desc){
  var slider = $(this);
  var slides = slider.find('li');
  slides.each(function(a,b){
    $(this).attr('data-slide',a);
    if(a == 0){
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    if(a > 0){
      $(this).addClass('inactive');
    }
  });

  var ua = navigator.userAgent;
  var events = (ua.match(/iPad/i)) ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
  slider.find('.arrows')
            .on(events,function(e){
    if($(this).hasClass('left')){
      slider.find('.active')
                .slideLeft(slider);
      /*slider.find('.active')
                .slideDown(slider);*/
    }
    if($(this).hasClass('right')){
      slider.find('.active')
                .slideRight(slider);
      /*slider.find('.active')
                .slideUp(slider);*/
    }
    slider.slideInfo(desc);
  });
}

$.fn.slideLeft = function(slider){
  var slide = $(this);
  slide.css({'left':'0'});
  slider.find('li:not(.active)')
            .css({'left':'-100%'});

  var next = slide.prev('li');
  if(
    parseInt(slide.attr('data-slide'))
        <=
    0
  ){
    next = slider.find('li')
                         .last();
  }

  slide.stop()
         .animate({'left':'100%'},600)
         .css({'left':'-100%'});
  next.stop()
        .animate({'left':'0'},600);

  slide.removeClass('active')
         .addClass('inactive');
  next.removeClass('inactive')
        .addClass('active');
}

$.fn.slideRight = function(slider){
  var slide = $(this);
  slider.find('li:not(.active)')
            .css({'left':'100%'});
  slide.css({'left':'0'});

  var next = slide.next('li');
  if(
    parseInt(slide.attr('data-slide')) + 1
        >= 
    slider.find('li').length
  ){
    next = slider.find('li')
                         .first();
  }

  slide.stop()
         .animate({'left':'-100%'},600)
         .css({'left':'100%'});
  next.stop()
        .animate({'left':'0'},600);

  slide.removeClass('active')
         .addClass('inactive');
  next.removeClass('inactive')
        .addClass('active');
}

$.fn.slideUp = function(slider){
  var slide = $(this);
  slider.find('li:not(.active)')
            .css({'top':'-100%'});
  slide.css({'top':'0'});

  var next = slide.next('li');
  if(
    parseInt(slide.attr('data-slide')) + 1
        >= 
    slider.find('li').length
  ){
    next = slider.find('li')
                         .first();
  }

  slide.stop()
         .animate({'top':'100%'},600)
         .css({'top':'-100%'});
  next.stop()
        .animate({'top':'0'},600);

  slide.removeClass('active')
         .addClass('inactive');
  next.removeClass('inactive')
        .addClass('active');
}

$.fn.slideDown = function(slider){
  var slide = $(this);
  slide.css({'top':'0'});
  slider.find('li:not(.active)')
            .css({'top':'100%'});

  var next = slide.prev('li');
  if(
    parseInt(slide.attr('data-slide'))
        <=
    0
  ){
    next = slider.find('li')
                         .last();
  }

  slide.stop()
         .animate({'top':'-100%'},600)
         .css({'top':'100%'});
  next.stop()
        .animate({'top':'0'},600);

  slide.removeClass('active')
         .addClass('inactive');
  next.removeClass('inactive')
        .addClass('active');
}

$.fn.slideInfo = function(el){
  var alt = $(this).find('.active img')
                                 .attr('alt');
  var title = $(this).find('.active img')
                                     .attr('title');
  $(el).find('.title')
         .text(title);
  $(el).find('.description')
         .text(alt);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider').slideIt('.picture-description');
  $('.slider').slideInfo('.picture-description');
});
```

For some reason, the element flashes for a millisecond before every transition, and on switching of tabs and such, it doesn't do the action immediately (i.e. it goes blank for a second then just switches to the next slide).

I'm not sure why this is happening and would appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Have you tried using just CSS transitions instead of JQuery?  It looks like you're using a mix of the two, I've only just had a short look through the code so far though.

Comment: I've used it for the buttons and arrangement of the slides, but to actually do the slides, because I wanted the transition as it is (albeit, without the flash) I used jQuery, the classes that are added and removed are for ease of traversion, not adding or removing styles, the z-index is only there because I thought for some reason it could be flashing over it on the transition but apparently it isn't.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how I would do this with sole css transitions as well

Comment: I can put something together in a little bit.  Basically you'd just want to use JQuery to add/remove classes from your divs and update the titles.  You can leave the actual transition stuff to CSS.  I'll pen up something on CodePen and post it later today.

Comment: Mmm, I probably won't have time to refactor this and get a good solution, but here's a blog post about something very similar I did.  It's not doing any of the media query stuff, but basically the way it's structured allowed me to add any number of images and simply rotate through them.  You could modify this to do what you're doing here, rotating based off of your arrow functions and simply setting the next and previous states to hidden locations in the overflow and then modifying the title in the function.

http://blog.wakeskaterstudio.com/2014/09/creating-rotating-gallery-game-page.html

Comment: It appears to have stopped after changing slide.stop().animate({'left':'100%'},600).css({'left':'-100%'}); to slide.stop().animate({left:'100%'},600,function(){slide.animate({left:'-100%'},0);});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been with using a combination of jquery css and animation. Changing it all to animate such as:

```
  slide.stop()
         .animate({left:'100%'},600,
                function(){
                                slide.animate({left:'-100%'},0);
                            });
  next.stop()
        .animate({'left':'0'},600);
```

instead of

```
  slide.stop()
         .animate({'left':'100%'},600)
         .css({'left':'-100%'});
  next.stop()
        .animate({'left':'0'},600);
```